# setup routing for homepage

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have two routes in my `RouteConfig.cs` file. I'm not able to run both at the same time so the one on top gets executed:

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "ScNewsList",
        "{controller}/{id}/{title}",
        new { controller = "news", action = "SpecialCollectionList", id = UrlParameter.Optional, title = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
          name: "Default",
          url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
          defaults: new { controller = "home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

How do i gets rules running for both:

```
http://localhost:53098/news/312/SpecialCollectionList
http://localhost:53098/
```

The second one should mapped to homepage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're meaning to always have your ScNewsList route run against the news controller, then you can update the url to be `"news/{id}/{title}"`.

That way your `Default` route will be a catch all outside of the `ScNewsList` route.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it this way by manually setting the route to news

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "ScNewsList",
    "news/{id}/{title}",
    new { controller = "news", action = "SpecialCollectionList", id =     UrlParameter.Optional, title = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
      name: "Default",
      url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
      defaults: new { controller = "home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```